# github-linguist command shows the correct statistics but GitHub server is not getting updated after a few days

Tags: github, github-linguist

I've been trying to work with github-linguist for a while and it still gives a bit of problem.

After a few days of trying to figure out different issues with the language statistics, I managed to set .githubattributes with the right commands to get the correct statistics from github-linguist command:

[image]

But in GitHub's webpage/server it's still not showing up:

[image]

This is the link to the repo I am working on: https://github.com/FeriBolour/cotton-phenotyping

I tried different solutions:

1. Waited almost a week.
2. Pushed meaningless stuff to the repo to update the server.

It's still not working. What do you suggest me to do.

Answer (score 0):

It could be two things:

1. It's not computing statistics on the branch you expect. GitHub only displays statistics for the default branch, but I believe locally you can compute statistics for any branch.
2. There's a bug on GitHub's side that caused the statistics update to be cancelled. I've seen that happen before while working on Linguist. I suspect it happens when the statistic-update job queue grows too large and jobs are dropped.

In your case, it's not problem 1 because you appear to have only one branch on this repository. It's most likely problem 2. You can **contact GitHub support** and they should have a way to **manually trigger a statistic update for your repository**.